# jQuery Adding new option to select element doesn't pick up the string

Tags: jquery, html, css, string, select

I'm trying to add a new option to each select element and have it display the option value just like how 'US California" displays, for example I added an option to US-select but when selected, 'US California' still displays. Any ideas why?

Here's a js fiddle to demonstrate what I mean : http://bit.ly/1aU1n5E

Thank you

Comment: Please post your code here and don't try to sidestep the SO rule of posting your code when linking to jsFiddle.net.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the problem you're describing is. Can you clarify, or reiterate? And, as j08691 said: bring your JavaScript and HTML into your question. Don't use URL-shorteners to cheat Stack Overflow's requirement of code, if you happen to post a link to JS Fiddle (or elsewhere).

Comment: The fact that you went through the effort of shorting the URL rather than just copy and pasting the JS is truly baffling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
var str = $('#country-select').val() + " " + $("#" + $("#country-select option:selected").val() + "-select option:selected").val();
```

to:

```
var str = $('#country-select, .sub-menu').val() + " " + $("#" + $("#country-select option:selected").val() + "-select option:selected").val();
```

**[jFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T3egq/3/)**

You need to trigger the change on both the first and second selects, so `$('#country-select, .sub-menu')` is needed.